# Getting the error google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: File not found. on moving to protobuf javalite from protobuf java

Tags: android, firebase, protobuf-java

Below is what code I have added in my gradle file to solve duplicate GeneratedMessageLite class issue in protobuf upon which I am getting the error:

> Cause: protoc: stdout: . stderr: google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: File not found.

> google/api/annotations.proto:20:1: Import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto" was not found or had errors.

> google/api/annotations.proto:26:8: "google.protobuf.MethodOptions" is not defined.
> google/api/annotations.proto:19:1: warning: Import google/api/http.proto but not used.

```
android{
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }

    configurations.all {
        exclude group:'com.google.api.grpc',module:'proto-google-common-protos'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava',module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
    }

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.31.1"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.31.1"
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.12.0'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:1.24.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1:1.23.0';

}
```